# how to speed up nested loop? Python

Tags: python, numpy, loops, vectorization

```
def model_predykycjny(r):
    macierz_R = np.zeros((r, r))
    for i in range(1, r + 1):
        for j in range(1, r + 1):
            suma_iloczynow = 0
            if i <= j:
                # I want to speed up this loop
                for n in range(r, len(fixed_data_channel0)):
                    suma_iloczynow += float(fixed_data_channel0[n - i]) * float(fixed_data_channel0[n - j])
                macierz_R[i - 1][j - 1] = (np.float(suma_iloczynow))
            suma_iloczynow = 0
```

```
time for r =3 : 7.9424097537994385
```

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then consider modifying your question to give more detail

Answer (score 0):

You might use `range`s so you would need not to check `i<=j`, consider that

```
r = 3
for i in range(1, r+1):
    for j in range(1, r+1):
        if i<=j:
            print(i,j)
```

is equivalent to

```
r = 3
for i in range(1, r+1):
    for j in range(i, r+1):
        print(i,j)
```